# Entity Framework with filtered index - "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following simplified table definition and filtered unique index in a database that sits behind an MVC web app using Entity Framework 6.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemImage](
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [stream_id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    [Primary] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Caption] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemImage_ItemId_stream_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ItemId] ASC, [stream_id] ASC)
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemImage_ItemId_Item] FOREIGN KEY([ItemId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Item] ([ItemId])
);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UXF_ItemImage_ItemId_Primary]
    ON [dbo].[ItemImage] ([ItemId] ASC)
    WHERE ([Primary] = 1);
GO
```

The unique index prevents more than one `[ItemId]` having the `[Primary]` bit flag set.

In the MVC controller, I have a collection of `ItemImage` view models that I am updating the EF model with as follows:

```
...
foreach (var img in itemViewModel.ItemImages)
{
    var itemImage = item.ItemImages.First(i => i.stream_id == img.stream_id);

    itemImage.Primary = img.Primary;
    itemImage.Caption = img.Caption;
}
...
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When `db.SaveChangesAsync()` is called I get the following exception:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ItemImage' with unique index 'UXF_ItemImage_ItemId_Primary'. The duplicate key value is (146).
>   The statement has been terminated.

I have logic prior to the update that prevents an `Item` having multiple "primary" `ItemImages`.

I think this is happening because when Entity Framework is trying to update the collection of ItemImages in the database it's setting another row's `[Primary]` flag to `1` before unsetting the currently set row.

Is there a way to force an order of update in Entity Framework? Or is there a workaround I can implement?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient method but it's now working using the following.

```
foreach (var img in itemViewModel.ItemImages.Where(i => ! i.Primary))
{
    var itemImage = item.ItemImages.First(i => i.stream_id == img.stream_id);
    itemImage.Primary = img.Primary;
    itemImage.Caption = img.Caption;
}

await db.SaveChangesAsync();

var primaryImage = itemViewModel.ItemImages.First(i => i.Primary);
var itemImagePrimary = item.ItemImages.First(i => i.stream_id == primaryImage.stream_id);
itemImagePrimary.Primary = primaryImage.Primary;
itemImagePrimary.Caption = primaryImage.Caption;

await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Essentially I'm just updating all the "non-primary" `ItemImages` in batch at first, committing the changes, then updating the new "primary".

Comment: This looks like the correct way, AFAIK, you can't control the order of commands. I'd wrap this all in a transaction though (using `db.Database.BeginTransaction()`) just to prevent half-baked updates if anything else goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method is to push the update to the database layer by way of a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspItemImage_SetPrimary]
    @itemId INT
,   @stream_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM [dbo].[ItemImage] WHERE [ItemId] = @itemId AND [stream_id] = @stream_id )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @stream_id_vc NVARCHAR(36) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), NEWID());
        RAISERROR(  N'No ItemImage exists with ItemId = %d and stream_id = ''%s''',
                11,
                1,
                @itemId,
                @stream_id_vc);
    END;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE
        [dbo].[ItemImage]
    SET
        [Primary] = 0
    WHERE
        [ItemId] = @itemId;

    UPDATE
        [dbo].[ItemImage]
    SET
        [Primary] = 1
    WHERE
        [ItemId] = @itemId AND
        [stream_id] = @stream_id;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    RETURN 0;

END;
```

After importing the stored procedure into the entity framework model as `SetPrimaryItemImage`, I can simply do the following:

```
...
foreach (var img in itemViewModel.Images)
{
    var itemImage = item.ItemImages.First(i => i.stream_id == img.stream_id);
    itemImage.Caption = img.Caption;
}
await db.SaveChangesAsync();

db.SetPrimaryItemImage(item.ItemId, itemViewModel.Images.First(i => i.Primary).stream_id);   
...
```